# Select periods from days of week and time

Tags: python, pandas

```
            A         B          C
0  2001-01-13  10:00:00   Saturday
1  2001-01-14  12:33:00     Sunday
2  2001-01-20  15:10:00   Saturday
3  2001-01-24  13:15:00  Wednesday
4  2001-01-24  16:56:00  Wednesday
5  2001-01-24  19:09:00  Wednesday
6  2001-01-28  19:14:00     Sunday
7  2001-01-29  11:00:00     Monday
8  2001-01-29  23:50:00     Monday
9  2001-01-30  11:50:00    Tuesday
10 2001-01-30  13:00:00    Tuesday
11 2001-02-02  16:14:00  Wednesday
12 2001-02-02  09:25:00     Friday
```

I want to create a new df containing rows between all periods *from Mondays at 12:00:00 to Wednesdays at 17:00:00*

The output would be:

```
            A         B          C
3  2001-01-24  13:15:00  Wednesday
5  2001-01-24  16:56:00  Wednesday
8  2001-01-29  23:50:00     Monday
9  2001-01-30  11:50:00    Tuesday
10 2001-01-30  13:00:00    Tuesday
11 2001-02-02  16:14:00  Wednesday
```

I tried with

```
df[(df["B"] >= "12:00:00") & (df["B"] <= "17:00:00")] & df[(df["C"] >= "Monday") & (df["C"] <= "Wednesday")]
```

But this is not what I want.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create 3 boolean masks and filter by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) - first for first day with starts time, second for all day between and last for last day and end time:

```
from datetime import time
#if necessary convert to datetime
df['A'] = pd.to_datetime(df['A'])
#if necessary convert to times
df['B'] = pd.to_datetime(df['B']).dt.time

m1 = (df['B']>=time(12)) & (df['C'] == 'Monday')
m2 = (df['C'] == 'Tuesday')
m3 = (df['B']<=time(17)) & (df['C'] == 'Wednesday')
df = df[m1 | m2 | m3]
print (df)
            A         B          C
3  2001-01-24  13:15:00  Wednesday
4  2001-01-24  16:56:00  Wednesday
8  2001-01-29  23:50:00     Monday
9  2001-01-30  11:50:00    Tuesday
10 2001-01-30  13:00:00    Tuesday
12 2001-02-02  09:25:00  Wednesday
```

Another solution with same times from `Monday` to `Friday`:

```
from datetime import time
df['A'] = pd.to_datetime(df['A'])
df['B'] = pd.to_datetime(df['B']).dt.time

m1 = (df['B']>=time(12)) & (df['C'] == 'Monday')
m2 = df['C'].isin(['Tuesday', 'Wednesday'])
m3 = (df['B']<=time(17)) & (df['C'] == 'Friday')
df = df[m1 | m2 | m3]
print (df)
            A         B          C
3  2001-01-24  13:15:00  Wednesday
4  2001-01-24  16:56:00  Wednesday
5  2001-01-24  19:09:00  Wednesday
8  2001-01-29  23:50:00     Monday
9  2001-01-30  11:50:00    Tuesday
10 2001-01-30  13:00:00    Tuesday
11 2001-02-02  16:14:00     Friday
12 2001-02-02  09:25:00  Wednesday
```

Answer (score 0):

Use OR (|) operator and equal (=), instead of & and <=, >=). Hope it helps. Thanks.

```
old: df[(df["B"] >= "12:00:00") & (df["B"] <= "17:00:00")] & df[(df["C"] >= "Monday") & (df["C"] <= "Wednesday")]
New: df[(df["B"] >= "12:00:00") & (df["B"] <= "17:00:00")] & (df[(df["C"] = "Monday") | (df["C"] = "Tuesday") | (df["C"] = "Wednesday"))]
```